# Assign directory to variable in a source file

Tags: linux, bash, variables, directory, tab-completion

I am building a source file with some alias to executable files (these are working just fine) and assigning directories to variables in order to get to the directory quicker, with less typing. For example, if I source example.source:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mydir="/path/to/some/dir"
```

I can get to `/path/to/some/dir` with

```
cd $mydir
```

However, I am not being able to use tab complete to navigate through other sub-directories like I would do by typing the complete path. I mean, if I use the tab key to complete the variable I get `cd $mydir` but not `cd $mydir/` (I have to delete the last space character and manually type the slash / to see the next sub-directories). Hope this is an understandable question. Is there any workaround for this?

**EDIT:** the linux distribution I'm using is Slackware Linux 3.2.31.c x86_64 GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

**EDIT2:** GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release

Comment: I don't know of any way to get tab completion to know that you want it to do that but you could stick the trailing slash in the variable and use `cd ${myd<tab>` which would complete to `cd ${mydir}` and you could then skip needing to type the slash at least. (Though cd here doesn't complete variable names for me so I don't know what's going on.)

Comment: ok, thanks, I am able to do tab completion on variables in my system (Linux 3.2.31.c x86_64, Slackware)

Comment: Oh, I can tab complete variables, just not with `cd`.

Comment: Post the output of `complete -p cd`.

Comment: @Cyrus it is in a server so I don't have really control over these kind of things  > complete -p cd
-bash: complete: cd: no completion specification

Comment: @PedroA: please add name and version of your distribution to your question.

Comment: Ah, that `complete` bit explains the tab completion behaviour difference.

Comment: I suppose you could write your own complete handler for `cd` which completes variables but doesn't append the space

Comment: @Etan and how could I accomplish that?

Comment: Write a shell function that uses `complete` and `compgen` (etc.) and set that as the `complete` handler for `cd` (with appropriate top-level options to control spaces, etc.). It almost looked as if the default complete options could do what you wanted but here at least (`bash 3.2.25`) they didn't work together the way you would want. You could try playing with the `-o nospace`, `-o dirnames`, `-o plusdirs`, and/or `-o bashdefault` along with `-A variable`/`-v` as arguments to `complete ... cd` and see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this feature is starting to be implemented in bash 4.3, release 26-Feb-2014 09:25.

Reading the NEWS file in bash 4.3 I found this:

> i.  The word completion code checks whether or not a filename
>   containing a
>       shell variable expands to a directory name and appends `/' to the word
>       as appropriate.  The same code expands shell variables in command names
>       when performing command completion.

Unfortunately I cannot do a de novo installation of bash (because I'm working on a server) but I hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then I believe it can be solved by putting this at the top of your `example.source`. This will list your contents every-time that you cd.

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

    # Make cd change directories and then list the contents
    function cd() {
        builtin cd $*;
        ls;
    }

    mydir="/path/to/some/dir"
    cd $mydir
```

My other suggestion is to try to put cd within your alias. Something like this:

```
    mydir="cd /path/to/some/dir"
    $mydir
```

Comment: I don't believe either of those even comes close to answering the question. He wants to be able to tab complete the variable name and then continue tab completing paths inside that directory.